# Runtime Error on Factorial recursive method Python

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, factorial

```
def recursive_factorial(n):
   if n == 1: #base case
       return 1
   else:  
       return n * recursive_factorial(n-1) #recursive call
```

pls help I am getting a runtime error:RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth exceeded'

Comment: It works for me, assuming `num` passed to a function is actually an `int`.
Show how you call this function when it fails.

Comment: you most likely passed a `float` in. I would suggest changing `n==1` to `n <= 1` to deal with passing "int-like floats" (such as if `n = 5.0`)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

So, you have reached your recursion limit.  This can be reset by importing sys and setting but:

[Seriously don't use setrecursionlimit](http://seriously.dontusethiscode.com/2013/04/14/setrecursionlimit.html)

You definitely try to iterate before using recursion.  Please try this, which should work if you *cannot* set recursion limits:

```
re(n):
  g=n
  while n>1:
    g*=(n-1)
    n-=1
  return g
```

If you really, really want to set your recursion limit, make sure that you do so only temporarily.  Otherwise other, heavier, functions may create issues if too recursive:

```
import sys
def thing_i_want_to_recurse(n)
  c_limit = sys.getrecursionlimit()
  sys.setrecurionlimit(n)
  yield
  sys.setrecurionlimit(c_limit)
```

Again iteration is best:

```
 [in]: sys.setrecursionlimit(3)
 [in]: recursive_factorial(5)
 [out]:Error: maximum recusion depth exceeded
 [in]: re(5) #no problem
 [out]: 120
```

Comment: I am currently running the code online as I am writing a proctor test. I tried using import but it gave me errors because I am not allowed to use import command. Is there any other methods

Comment: @bgreatfit i got you

Comment: Using `sys.setrecursionlimit` like this isn't a good idea: there's a reason that that recursion limit is there in the first place, namely to prevent the Python process from blowing the C stack. If you're going to change the recursion limit, you also need to make sure that you're doing whatever's necessary to make corresponding enlargements to the stack allocated to your process (e.g., using `ulimit` in bash).